# page_source content does not change when using browser.page_source to read

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

The target page url is "http://data.eastmoney.com/gzfx/list.html"
There is a table of stock list at the bottom of this page, and it has 70+ pages, you can move to other pages by click next ("下一页"), but the link of the page never change, it is always show "http://data.eastmoney.com/gzfx/list.html"

I used selenium to click the next page and use "html_code=browser.page_source" to get the content of the html, but I never get the content of the new page, it always show the first page.

I have tried to use "browser.refresh()" to get the page refreshed, but it will go back to the first page, the second page share the same link with first page.

My question is how to get the updated page content after I click the next button.

below is my code:

```
import html5lib
import re 
import time 
import random 
import json 
import sys 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url="http://data.eastmoney.com/gzfx/list.html"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)


html_code=browser.page_source
soupcontent = soup(html_code,'html5lib')

while True:
    scripts = soupcontent.find_all('script')
    jsonObj = None
    for script in scripts:
        if 'pageData =' in script.text:
            jsonStr = script.text
            jsonStr = jsonStr.split("pageData =")[1]
            jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
    products = jsonObj['data']

    for item in products:
        serialno=item['SECURITYCODE']
        stockname=item['SName']
        industry=item['HYName']
        market=item['MKT']        
        print (serialno+'\t'+stockname+'\t'+industry+'\t'+market+'\n')

    browser.find_element_by_link_text('下一页').click()
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    html_code=browser.page_source
    soupcontent = soup(html_code)
```

how can I get the update content of the new page?

Thank you!

Comment: please remove all code except what is relevant to the question

Comment: Sorry, the only relevant code is: "html_code=browser.page_source". After the browser opened the second page, I could not get the updated the html content by using "html_code=browser.page_source".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the page doesn't change on Javascript triggered update of the content.

Instead of getting page source, try to get the content of the body element. something like that (code not tested)

```
html_code = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")).text
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried, but seems it still get the same content of first page. you do see the page changed to next page in chrome browser, the the content didn't change by using "html_code=browser.page_source" or "html_code = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text"

Comment: Thank you! I tried again, it works and get get the updated content. Thank you!